# jQuery - how to register a callback for an asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a jQuery newbie. I have a core js file which will not be visible to my user. I have the following function inside it that makes a server request -

```
function checkMsgs(t1,t2) {

// poll the url
    // return the results 

    $.get("http://www.mySite.com/web/test.php", {
        "t1" : t1,
            "t2" : t2
    }, function(data) {
    return data;
});

}
```

Now, I want to call this function, without blocking the thread i.e., asynchronously. How do I make a function call after it returns from this method, but without blocking anything?

Comment: The `function(data) { return data; }` is the callback function for the AJAX call. Or did I misunderstood you?

Comment: It shouldn't block anything in the first place

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot "return" from `$.get`, it doesn't work that way.  What you want to do is pass a callback to `checkMsgs` and call it when `$.get` is done.

```
function checkMsgs(t1, t2, callback) {
    $.get("http://www.mySite.com/web/test.php", {
        "t1": t1,
        "t2": t2
    }, function (data) {
        // do whatever...
        $.isFunction(callback) && callback(data);
    });
}
```

Then you call `checkMsgs` like this:

```
checkMsgs('a', 'b', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: There is also one enough `jquery` approach of checking the variable type: `$.isFunction(callback)` :)

Comment: @VisioN: Neat, didn't know about that :-P

Answer (score 6):

Return the `$.get` from the function and add a callback to it.

```
function checkMsgs(t1,t2) {
    return $.get("http://www.mySite.com/web/test.php");
}

checkMsg("foo","bar").done(function(){
    alert("It's Done!");
});
```